# How to integrate barcode scanner directly on my app?

Tags: qr-code

Does anyone here knows how to to integrate barcode scanning directly into an application without having the separate ZXing application installed?

Answer (score 0):

The complete source code to Barcode Scanner is here: http://code.google.com/p/zxing

As a developer of the library, I can tell you that two things happen in 95% of cases where someone tries to integrate our source code into their app:

- They find it's quite a bit of work to adapt the code and integrate and maintain the scanning in their own app, and they use the Intent API
- They copy and paste our code and try to make "their own" app this way

I can tell you we do not want developers to copy and paste our source code. And unless you're an experienced Android dev, you will have trouble re-inventing a scanning app on your own

Bottom line: save yourself the trouble and integrate via Intent: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Comment: i actually did that already. but it was returned to me and i was asked to me was to create a standalone scanner. they don't want any third party application  (for whatever reason it is). i do understand the why you do not want us to copy-paste your code. i also don't want to take credit for things i didn't do. thanks for your response and also for sharing  the lib.  :)

Answer (score -1):

try to use the Google Chart tool api its very simple, i have a function that i wrote a while back:

```
function get_QR_code($content = null,$size = null,$ImgTag = true){
    if ($size == null){
        $size = '150x150';
    }
    if ($ImgTag){
        echo '<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs='.$size.'&choe=UTF-8&chld=H&chl='.$content .'">';
    }else{
        return 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs='.$size.'&choe=UTF-8&chld=H&chl='.$content;
    }
}

<?php get_QR_code('Hello form Google API'); ?>
```

Comment: That's encoding, not decoding.